# How to use deleteCharactersInRange?

Tags: string, swift, nsrange

I want do call the method "deleteCharactersInRange" but it doesn't work.

This is an excerpt from Apples Documentation:

> Swift
>
> func deleteCharactersInRange(_ aRange: NSRange)

```
    var day = ""

    let stringRange:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 4)
    day = day.deleteCharacterInRange(stringRange)


    // I've also tried this, because in the Documentation 
    // I can't see wether the method is void or returns a String

    day.deleteCharacterInRange(stringRange)
```

I get this error message:

> 'String' does not have a member named 'deleteCharactersInRange'

Comment: You've got a typo.  You're missing an `s`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method you're citing belongs to [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/deleteCharactersInRange:). But since you're using Swift and haven't explicitly created one, you get a Swift `String`.

If you want to operate on Swift `String`, you need to use `str.removeRange` and the rather awkward to use `Range`:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
str.removeRange(Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex, end:advance(str.startIndex, 7)))
// "playground"
```

Comment: Thank you, but what does this "Range<String.Index>" mean/do? Is this also a kind of method and if yes what kind?

Comment: To break down this answer..., `Range<String.Index>(/*stuff*/)` is equivalent (roughly) to the `NSMakeRange` function.  It's an initializer for the Swift `Range` struct.

Comment: `day.removeRange(Range<String.Index>(start: 0, end: 4))`  This code does not work, I get the error message "Extra argument 'end' in call"

Comment: You have to use the `str.startIndex` and the `advance` function.

Comment: end:advance(day.startIndex, 4)

Comment: Ok and what if I want the start not to be at the beginning, but lets say at Index 4?

Comment: `let startIndex = advance(str.startIndex, 4)`

Comment: You don't even need to call the constructor of `Range` directly. Instead you can do something like: `str.removeRange(str.startIndex..<advance(str.startIndex, 7))`

Comment: but what the heck is "startIndex"? Is it always the character at index 0? If so then why the heck do they have this gobbledegook syntax?

Comment: @CommaToast: Yes, it's always the first character. Correctly assigning a number to a character position is tricky and error-prone, which is why Swift doesn't do this and instead uses a _Index_ class/struct. See the [Swift blog entry about Strings in Swift 2.0](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30) why it's tricky; at least look at the table near the end. For more gory details, see the [Swift String documentation, section _String Indices_](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

Answer (score 4):

In light of *DarkDust*'s answer, we can make a very Swift-like `extension` that will make `removeRange` easier to use:

```
extension String {
    mutating func deleteCharactersInRange(range: NSRange) {
        let startIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location)
        let length = range.length
        self.removeRange(startIndex ..< startIndex.advancedBy(length))
    }
}
```

Now you can use it as such:

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0,4)
var day = "Tuesday"
day.deleteCharactersInRange(range) // day = "day"
```

Comment: Ok, my problem was that I thought Apple removed all of this "Mutable-" thing and instead use var and let.

Comment: @Codey See my most recent edit.  Use the String extension at the top of my answer rather than the one at the bottom.

Comment: In the first Code block line 3. Does the self refer to the string that is calling the function? And what does the keyword "mutating" do for the function?

Comment: Yes.  The word `mutating` allows a function to modify `self`.  `struct`'s functions aren't allowed to modify `self` unless they are marked as `mutating`.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: Where do I declare an extension so that all of the classes in my project can make use of it?

Comment: In Swift, anywhere.  For code cleanliness and organization, I'd probably just create a new file though and put it there by itself (plus other useful String extensions you might have or use)

Answer (score 3):

**Update for Swift 3**

In Swift 3 it is required to use the range operators `a..<b` or `a...b`.

```
var aString = "This is just the beginning"
str.removeRange(Range<String.Index>(str.startIndex ..< str.startIndex.advancedBy(10)))
```

or even more concise

```
aString.removeRange(aString.startIndex..<aString.startIndex.advancedBy(10))
```